# Not submit data in mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here i tried to store form data in my mongodb database(mongodb compass).
but after submit when i check than there are nothing in my database.

when i press sign up button than it's show me just curly brackets.

App.js file(main file)

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const port = 8081;
    require('./db/conn');
    const path = require("path");
    const hbs = require("hbs");
    const register = require("./models/register");
    
    const static_path  = path.join(__dirname,"../public");
    const template_path = path.join(__dirname,"../templates/views");
    const partials_path = path.join(__dirname,"../templates/partials");
    
    app.set("views",template_path);
    app.set("view engine","hbs");
    hbs.registerPartials(partials_path);
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
    
    app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
        res.render("signup");
    })
    
    app.get("/signup",(req,res)=>{
        res.render("index");
    })
    
    app.get("/register",(req,res)=>{
        res.render("register");
    })
    
    app.post("/register",async(req,res)=>{
        try{
            const password = req.body.password;
            const cpassword = req.body.cpassword;
            if(password===cpassword){
                
                const registerEmployee = new Register({
                   firstname : req.body.firstname,
                   lastname : req.body.lastname,
                   email : req.body.email,
                   phone : req.body.phone,
                   age : req.body.age, 
                   password: req.body.password,          
            })

            const registered = await registerEmployee.save();
            console.log(registered);
            }
            else{
                res.send("password not matched");
            }
            res.send(registered);
        }catch(error){
           res.status(404).send(error)
        }
    })
    
    app.listen(port,()=>{
        console.log("succesfully port");
    })
```

register.js file(here i define mongoose.schema file)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const employeeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstname :{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    lastname:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
    },
    phone:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
    },
    age:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
   },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
})

const Register = new mongoose.model("register",employeeSchema);

module.exports = Register;
```

signup.hbs file(html form)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/signin.css">
    <title>Create New Account</title>


</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <div class="signin-form">
        <form action="/register" method="POST">
            <div class="form-header">
                <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                <h2>Fill out this form and start chatting with your friends.</h2><br>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <br>
                <lable>firstname</lable>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="Username"  />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <br>
                <lable>lastname</lable>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Username"  />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <br>
                <lable>email Address</lable>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="someone@site.com"  />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <br>
                <lable>phone Number</lable>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="contact number"  />
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <br>
                <lable>Age</lable>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="age"  />
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label> Password </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password"  />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Confirm Password </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cpassword" placeholder="confirm password"  />
            </div>
            
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" /> <label>i accept <a href="#">terms</a> and <a href="#">condition</a></label> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg " name="sign_up">Sign_Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="text-center small" style="color:#67428B;"> Already have an Account ?<a href="/">Login</a> </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to put `new` before `mongoose.Schema` :

`const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema`

Comment: did you connect to your mangoDB database?

Comment: yes, you can see this in 4th line,                                                                                                                                        conn.js file                                                                                                             const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/youtuberegistration",{
    useCreateIndex:true,
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
}).then(()=>{
    console.log("connection successfully");
}).catch((e)=>{
    console.log(e);
})

Answer (score 0):

after so much time i solved error successfully, so i think i want to write here

here you can see in app file 7th line

const register = require("./models/register");

and when i enter new data then i use Register instead of register so there are an error.

const registerEmployee = new Register